# how can these 2 pointers have the same value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with this Code.The answer is 26 14 26 26.

Problem is, i keep finding x as 13.After the first fun function x and xptr becomes 13 but I can not figure out how it becomes 26.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* fun(int *a){
    *a = *a +5;
    return a;
}
int main(){
    int x, y, *xpntr, *ypntr;
    x = 3;
    xpntr = &x;
    fun(xpntr);
    y = 10 + (*xpntr / 2);
    ypntr = fun(xpntr);
    *ypntr = *xpntr + *ypntr;
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << *xpntr << " " << *ypntr << endl;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You beat me to it, NathanOliver.  @yesidaladam: your next step is absolutely to FAMILIARIZE YOURSELF with your debugger, and SINGLE-STEP through your program.  Inspect the value at each step.  Q: What is your compiler?  Does it have an IDE?  Which debugger(s) are available to you?  Please update your post with the answers.

Comment: Hint: in particular, to verify whether you are correct to believe that `ypntr` and `xpntr` point to different storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through your code step by step

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* fun(int *a){
```

The next line means: "get the value from the location where pointer `a` is pointing to, add 5 to it, and write it to the location pointer `a` is pointing to." *This does not change the pointer itself!*

```
    *a = *a +5;
```

Next return the pointer `a`, which is just the same value as was passed to the function

```
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int x, y, *xpntr, *ypntr;
    x = 3;
```

Assign to `xpntr` the memory location of `x`

```
    xpntr = &x;
```

Call `fun` with `xpntr`, discard what it returns. x will then be 3+5 = 8

```
    fun(xpntr);
```

Assign to `y` the result of 10 + ( *value of what `xpntr` is pointing to* / 2) – xpntr isn't changed by this. y = 10 + (8/2) = 14

```
    y = 10 + (*xpntr / 2);
```

Call `fun` with `xpntr`, something happens to what `xpntr` is pointing to, but as we already learnt, xpntr itself is not changed in the process. The value returned by `fun` (which is just `xpntr`) is assigned to `ypntr`. x will be changed again to 8 + 5 = 13

```
    ypntr = fun(xpntr);
```

Assign to where `ypntr` is pointing to (which is right now identical to `xpntr` to the sum of what's pointed to by `xpntr` and `ypntr`. So x will then be 13 + 13 = 26 **← this is where your 26 comes from!**

```
    *ypntr = *xpntr + *ypntr;
```

Print the values of where `xpntr` and `ypntr` point to.

```
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << *xpntr << " " << *ypntr << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Before your `ypntr = fun(xpntr);` line, `x=8`, and `xpntr` points to `x`.

Now's the tricky part: `ypntr = fun(xpntr)` changes the value of `x` to 13. And `fun` is returning a reference to `x` -- `ypntr` now points to `x` as well.

This means that both `xptr` and `yptr` will point to the same data.

Your last statement (`*ypntr = *xpntr + *ypntr`) simply doubles the value of `x`.

```
+---------------------------+----+----+------+------+
|           code            | x  | y  | xptr | yptr |
+---------------------------+----+----+------+------+
| x = 3;                    |  3 | ?  | ?    | ?    |
| xpntr = &x;               |  3 | ?  | &x   | ?    |
| fun(xpntr);               |  8 | ?  | &x   | ?    |
| y = 10 + (*xpntr / 2);    |  8 | 14 | &x   | ?    |
| ypntr = fun(xpntr);       | 13 | 14 | &x   | &x   |
| *ypntr = *xpntr + *ypntr; | 26 | 14 | &x   | &x   |
+---------------------------+----+----+------+------+
```